# Sharing a custom taxonomy with Multiple custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have created a Custom Taxonomy (**Softwares**) and shared it with my 3 Custom Post Types (**Casinos, Bonuses, Slots**) everything was going well but when I created a **term** (**netent**) in **Softwares(CT)** for custom post type **Casinos** it automatically shows in other Custom Post types (**Bonuses, Slots**) which is wrong.

I need same Custom Taxonomy (**Softwares**) and Term (**netent**) for all three Custom Post Types (**Casinos, Bonuses, Slots**) with different content. Is it possible to do it or is there any other alternative to do this?

Here, I am using this to share same CT with three CPT:

```
register_taxonomy( 'softwares', array( 'casinos','slot-games','casino-bonuses' ), $args );
```

Comment: If they need to be different then why would it be the same taxonomy? Create a different version of the taxonomy for each post type.

Comment: No, Taxonomy and term slug need to be same but term content must be different based on custom post type.

Answer (score -3):

Late but maybe make Softwares a custom post type, then casinos, bonuses and slots become taxonomies each with a custom template and use the terms in each template.